# How is this key working in sorting to make a maximum number from elements in an array

Tags: python, sorting

I have this code but I am not able to understand how it is working. It is arranging the numbers in an array in such a way that concatenating of numbers makes the biggest number. I just don't understand how that key is working.

```
def fucn(x):
    print(str(x) * 10)
    return str(x) * 10


arr = [23, 45, 65, 66, 7, 4, 67]
Result = sorted(arr, key=fucn, reverse=True)
print('\n' + ''.join([str(i) for i in Result]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That `* 10` does nothing as your list is sorted **alphabetically** (by returning string value from callback `str(x)`). That means that even sole string `7` comes before `67676767676767676767`.

If you remove that string converting and do just `return x * 10` then your biggest number will remain the biggest after multiplied by 10 and so your printed value will start with 67.

Edit: Regarding your comment in another answer, sorting alphabetically in computer languages means sorting by current character position in ASCII table (let's forget unicode or other charsets for now):

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

```
Dec  = Decimal Value
Char = Character

'5' has the int value 53
if we write '5'-'0' it evaluates to 53-48, or the int 5
if we write char c = 'B'+32; then c stores 'b'


Dec  Char                           Dec  Char     Dec  Char     Dec  Char
---------                           ---------     ---------     ----------
  0  NUL (null)                      32  SPACE     64  @         96  `
  1  SOH (start of heading)          33  !         65  A         97  a
  2  STX (start of text)             34  "         66  B         98  b
  3  ETX (end of text)               35  #         67  C         99  c
  4  EOT (end of transmission)       36  $         68  D        100  d
  5  ENQ (enquiry)                   37  %         69  E        101  e
  6  ACK (acknowledge)               38  &         70  F        102  f
  7  BEL (bell)                      39  '         71  G        103  g
  8  BS  (backspace)                 40  (         72  H        104  h
  9  TAB (horizontal tab)            41  )         73  I        105  i
 10  LF  (NL line feed, new line)    42  *         74  J        106  j
 11  VT  (vertical tab)              43  +         75  K        107  k
 12  FF  (NP form feed, new page)    44  ,         76  L        108  l
 13  CR  (carriage return)           45  -         77  M        109  m
 14  SO  (shift out)                 46  .         78  N        110  n
 15  SI  (shift in)                  47  /         79  O        111  o
 16  DLE (data link escape)          48  0         80  P        112  p
 17  DC1 (device control 1)          49  1         81  Q        113  q
 18  DC2 (device control 2)          50  2         82  R        114  r
 19  DC3 (device control 3)          51  3         83  S        115  s
 20  DC4 (device control 4)          52  4         84  T        116  t
 21  NAK (negative acknowledge)      53  5         85  U        117  u
 22  SYN (synchronous idle)          54  6         86  V        118  v
 23  ETB (end of trans. block)       55  7         87  W        119  w
 24  CAN (cancel)                    56  8         88  X        120  x
 25  EM  (end of medium)             57  9         89  Y        121  y
 26  SUB (substitute)                58  :         90  Z        122  z
 27  ESC (escape)                    59  ;         91  [        123  {
 28  FS  (file separator)            60  <         92  \        124  |
 29  GS  (group separator)           61  =         93  ]        125  }
 30  RS  (record separator)          62  >         94  ^        126  ~
 31  US  (unit separator)            63  ?         95  _        127  DEL
```

So if you have two strings "67" and "7" then Python checks the first character and finds that 55 is greater than 54 and so puts **string** "7" before "67" (reversed order == descending).

Answer (score 0):

Key it a function that serves as a key for the sort comparison.
If `arr = [23, 45, 65, 66, 7, 4, 67]` pass to your `func` it will be as:

```
[
    "23232323232323232323",
    "45454545454545454545",
    "65656565656565656565",
    "66666666666666666666",
    "7777777777",
    "4444444444",
    "67676767676767676767",
]
```

Try it sort

```
In [1]: sorted(str_list)                                                                       
Out[1]: 
['23232323232323232323',
 '4444444444',
 '45454545454545454545',
 '65656565656565656565',
 '66666666666666666666',
 '67676767676767676767',
 '7777777777']

In [2]: sorted(str_list, reverse=True)                                                         
Out[2]: 
['7777777777',
 '67676767676767676767',
 '66666666666666666666',
 '65656565656565656565',
 '45454545454545454545',
 '4444444444',
 '23232323232323232323']
```

so '7777777777' it was `7` in your list `arr` because

```
In [3]: str(7) * 10                                                                           
Out[3]: '7777777777'
```

etc
Anyway, please use http://www.pythontutor.com for understanding how it works.

Comment: Can you explain how  '67676767676767676767' is less than '7777777777'  I am confused about that part? And thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Strings are sorted lexicographically.  The character `'7'` is later lexicographically than the character `'6'`.  By the same reasoning, the string `'zero'` is later lexicographically than the string `'yesterday'` even though `'yesterday'` is a longer string.